# mysql help for expenses group by week

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i have the following tables in mysql:

**money:**

userid,date,amount

**expenses:**

userid,date,amount

i need a sql sentence(report) with totals(deposited money - amount used by user ) per week, and group by user, week

this is what i have so far:

```
SELECT   expenses.userid      AS user,
         MONTH(expenses.date) AS month,
         SUM(money.amount)    AS amount_money,
         SUM(expenses.amount) AS expenses_amount
FROM     expenses INNER JOIN money ON money.userid = expenses.userid
GROUP BY 1,2 WITH ROLLUP
```

(Monday is the first day of the week)

**Sample data:**

**money:**

> 2012-11-05    abustos     70000
>
> 2012-11-05    psepulveda  35000
>
> 2012-10-07    fmonsalves  45000
>
> 2012-09-07    abustos     55000
>
> 2012-09-07    abustos     50000
>
> 2012-08-09    abustos     100000
>
> 2012-08-21    csuarez     130000
>
> 2012-08-09    fmonsalves  100000

**expenses:**

> ```
> 2012-05-24    csuarez     30000
>
> 2012-08-29    csuarez     30000
>
> 2012-08-22    csuarez     7990
>
> 2012-08-22    csuarez     21220
>
> 2012-08-23    csuarez     45577
> ```

**i want something like this:**

user: csuarez

week: 19-08-2012 25-08-2012

money: 130000

expenses: 115898

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)?

Comment: i have used YEARWEEK, but amounts were not the same.

Comment: @user1977586 added the other query with `week` with `mode` for Monday to be the first day. Please give that a try.

Comment: Can you please provide your data as a set of DDLs (i.e. CREATE and INSERT statements).

Comment: @user1977586 Where does this come from `19-08-2012 25-08-2012`? :)

Comment: i just put the range of that week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To derive the date of the Monday "starting" a week, (weeks running from Monday to Sunday), you can use an expression like:

```
mydate + INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(mydate)-1,2-DAYOFWEEK(mydate),-6) DAY 
  AS starting_monday
```

Similarly, to derive the date value of the "ending" sunday of the week:

```
mydate + INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK(mydate)-1,8-DAYOFWEEK(mydate),0) DAY 
  AS ending_sunday
```

---

But that's not really the problem with the query, assuming that your table `money` represents deposits to an account (and not a balance), and that your `expenses` table represents withdrawals from the account.

It's possible that a user will have a week with withdrawal but no deposits, or a week with deposits and no withdrawals.  A query that uses an JOIN operation on the two tables has the possibility of excluding rows. And an OUTER JOIN solves only half the problem.

From your description, it really sounds like you want a query that includes all withdrawals and all deposits for the week.

One approach is to combine the rows from the two separate tables using a UNION ALL operation:

```
SELECT 'm' AS m_or_e
     , m.userid
     , m.date
     , m.amount
  FROM money
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'e'
     , e.userid
     , e.date
     , -1.00*e.amount AS amount
  FROM expenses
```

You could then reference that query as an inline view; but for large sets, that's going to 
exhibit problematic performance, due the creation of an intermediate (derived) table.

This is less than ideal:

```
SELECT t.userid
     , t.week_
     , SUM(t.amount) AS total
     , SUM(IF(t.source='m',t.amount,0)) AS amount_money
     , SUM(IF(t.source='e',t.amount,0)) AS expenses_amount
  FROM (
         SELECT 'm' AS source
              , m.userid
              , YEARWEEK(m.date,1) AS week_
              , SUM(m.amount) AS amount
           FROM money m
          GROUP BY m.userid, week_
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'e' AS source
              , e.userid
              , YEARWEEK(e.date,1) AS week_
              , -1.00*SUM(e.amount)
           FROM expenses e
          GROUP BY e.userid, week_
        ) t
 GROUP BY t.userid, t.week_
```

---

For a query like this, ideally, the "deposits" and "withdrawals" would be recorded in the same table, with deposits and withdrawals stored as positive and negative amounts, or an identifier that distinguishes between "money" and "expenses".

I also don't see a primary key or unique key noted on either of the tables, but adding a unique constraint on `userid,date` or even `userid,date,amount` could be problematic.

Comment: NOTE: the output from this query will include only "weeks" for a user when there is a row in either "money" or "expenses" for that week... a missing "week" for a user means there was no row in either table for that week.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
SELECT money.userid as user, 
yearweek(expenses.date) as `week`, 
sum(money.amount) as amount_money, 
sum(expenses.amount) as expenses_amount,
sum(money.amount - expenses.amount) as deposit 
FROM money
LEFT JOIN expense
ON money.userid = expenses.userid 
group by `week`, money.userid;
```

As per eggyal's comments you may use `mode` within `week` function to get the first Monday of the week. 
[Reference](http://w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php).

```
SELECT money.userid as user, 
week(expenses.date, 1) as `week`, 
sum(distinct money.amount) as amount_money, 
sum(distinct expenses.amount) as expenses_amount,
sum(money.amount - expenses.amount) as deposit 
FROM money 
LEFT JOIN expense
ON money.userid = expenses.userid 
group by `week`, money.userid;
```

Latter update after op has given sample data:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfd6c/5)

Comment: I uaed the left join assuming that a user should have money to spend, so user might not have expenses but must have money :)

Comment: You will want to use one of modes 1,3,5 or 7 in order for Monday to be treated as the first day of the week (per the OP's question).

Comment: @eggyal thanks :) sorry I have really slow net connection, will update the query.

Comment: Thank you both!! but that sentence multiplies amounts per user, that sentence make this result: userid=csuarez, week=201221, amount_money=630000, expenses_amount=180000,deposit=450000 where user in that week have only one row: userid=csuarez, amount=30000, date=2012-05-24

Comment: @user1977586 added `distinct` please try. BTW the yearweek seems to support mode as well. So you can choose either. Any chance you can show us a small sample of your data for both tables..

Comment: distinct? but what if there's two or more items sharing the same amount - or ami missing something?

Comment: it fixes the multiplies values but appears rows that did not have amount available from money's table. i'll edit post to add some sample data, thanks!

Comment: @user1977586 it's pretty bad my side for the connection. Let us see your sample data first. Worst case scenario we may have to have a nested query. ;)

Comment: @user1977586 please take a look at [the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfd6c/5) and comment.

Comment: thanks for the sqlfiddle test! but this is my problem now: http://postimage.org/image/6tkpjvclx/full/